# How do i use a button inside a loginview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have added a button inside a loginview, but then this code is not working, do i need some findcontrol like when i have textbox and so on inside a loginview !??

This is not working my loginview have the id="loginview2"

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the < asp:Button   in the html have the "btnSave_Click" attached to "Click"?

Comment: i have this  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Gem" ValidationGroup="Save" CssClass="btn btn-success" />